# Getting a "method not applicable" compilation error

Tags: java

Can anyone tell my why I am getting an error in line 15 for `count(s1)`? Below is my code and the exact message I am getting from eclipse:

> The method count(String, char) in the type LetterCount is not applicable for the arguments (String)

```java
package count;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String s = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        String s1 = input.next();

        System.out.println(s1 + "appears" + count(s1) + "time(s).");

    }
    public static int count(String s, char s1) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: That method expects 2 arguments, but you're passing only 1 to it. What exactly did you expect it to do?

Comment: the error message sounded like you are supposed to pass string and character for this `count` function, yet you are passing just `s1`.  is this correct?

Comment: i am also wondering why this title "return not working"... ?

Comment: Also, since several people have answered your question, you should mark the one that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Your method declaration expects two parameters, you're only passing one when you call it.

You probably want to pass the variable "s" as well.

Comment: So would that be count(s, s1) in the system.out.print section of the main method?

Comment: @user1019838 Correct (with the caveat I haven't run the code to see if it actually does what you want once it's called correctly :)

Comment: @user1019838 Not quite; you're declaring your single character as a string, and your method expects a character. Change on of them.

Answer (score 2):

You only passed one argument to count(Sring s, char s1)

Easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 2):

Modify this

```
System.out.println(s1 + "appears" + count(s1, someCharVariable) + "time(s).");
```

It requires 2 arguments and you are supplying only one.

It's the only error. I have copied your code and tested accordingly.

---

Try this. you will have to apply some condition to ensure that what is inputted through the statement `String s1 = input.next();` is a valid character in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String s = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
    String s1 = input.next();

    System.out.println(s1 + " appears " + count(s, s1.charAt(0)) + " time(s).");
}

public static int count(String s, char s1) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s1)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `s1` is supposed to be the `someCharVariable`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println(s1 + "appears" + count(s1) + "time(s).");`

should be:

`System.out.println(s1 + "appears" + count(s,s1) + "time(s).");`

Comment: ya, s1 should be changed to char.

Comment: I tried that, but I am still getting an error: - The method count(String, char) in the type LetterCount is not applicable for the arguments 
  (String, String)
 - The method count(String, char) in the type LetterCount is not applicable for the arguments (String)